# Elaboration on or Elaboration of?

Tags: prepositions

Thank you for your **elaboration on** the possible reasonings behind this result. 
 Thank you for your **elaboration of** the possible reasonings behind this result.

**Which one is correct?**

Answer (score 2):

Both are technically correct but sound unusual.  As a native speaker, I would instead say *Thank you for elaborating on the possible reasonings behind this result*.  If you had to stick to the noun form, *of* sounds much more natural than *on* in this instance.

Comment: Agreed.  To my ear (native speaker, NE USA), there's something arch-sounding and suggestive of sarcasm of the noun form of the OP.